# MAX Function SQL

Tags: sql, substring, max

I have a simple issue that shouldnt be such an issue

This is my SQL statement

```
SELECT MAX(right(Epr_plt_epr_num,5)) as max_num
FROM eprmaster
WHERE SUBSTRING(Epr_plt_epr_num, INSTR(Epr_plt_epr_num,'-')+1,2) = '16'
```

I have numbers in this field Epr_plt_epr_num like this
55-16-00017 <-- this is the maximum number in the field

I am trying to find the max of that field which in this case should be 17.

If I do `MAX(right(Epr_plt_epr_num,2))` I get 17. however if i do anything higher than that it returns 16. One less.

I need it to return 17. However it is returning 16.

Can I not do Max Right with numbers such as 00017?

Comment: sql server, oracle, mysql, etc ???

Comment: Life would be easier if those where three separate fields.

Comment: Please set up a SQL fiddle with the appropriate data (and database).  It seems pretty clear from your description that the issue is the data and not necessarily only the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your example, I assume the format of `Epr_plt_epr_num` is `xx-yy-zzzzz`

And you want to find the maximal value `zzzzz` where `yy=16`

```
SELECT MAX(CAST right(Epr_plt_epr_num,5) AS INT) as max_num
FROM eprmaster
WHERE left(right(Epr_plt_epr_num,6),2) = '16'
```